# How to route URLs to index.html for localized Angular application in lighttpd?

Tags: angular, configuration, lighttpd

Angular application is deployed into lighttpd server. For example user is browsing `example.com/product/12` and sends this link to somebody. Without URL rewriting, you get 404 error.

Given that:

- localized versions are in subdirectories, e.g. `/en`, `/it`, `/cn`
- each language subdirectory has its own `index.html`
- Angular generates chunks like `styles.920e98031c0f5e2e220f.css`

I want to rewrite URLs to `/language_code/index.html` only for non-existing files.

The first solutions is:

```
server.error-handler-404 = "/index.html"
```

But there are several `index.html` in directories for each localization.

Another approach is this:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "(?!\.\w+$)" => "/index.html" )
```

However:

- what if URL contains a dot but is a part of a route, e.g. `/user/my.nick`?
- Angular generates chunks with dots in file names (can be handled with more rewrite rules)

Third approach that doesn't work as intended (and probably less performant - we need to check file existence):

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
  "^/(de|en)/" => "/$1/index.html"
)
```

Do I understand this correctly? Does this mean: if requested file does not exist and path to file starts of `/de/` or `/en/`, then rewrite to `/de/index.html` or `/en/index.html`.

But all URLs are rewritten to `/de/index.html` or `/en/index.html` despite files exist.

What is proper configuration for localized Angular 2+ application?

Version:

- Lighttpd version: 1.4.59 (ssl)
- Docker image: sebp/lighttpd:latest

Answer (score 0):

Content-Negotiation using lighttpd [mod_magnet](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModMagnet) and lua:
https://wiki.lighttpd.net/AbsoLUAtion#Content-Negotiation

Edit: another option is for `server.error-handler-404` to point to a FastCGI or CGI script which determines the desired target for the missing file.